# Send result of query over email in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, excel, plsql, export, plsqldeveloper

I am not quite sure on what is the easiest and fastest way to send a query result over email in PL/SQL Developer.
I have a big PL/SQL package which is doing a lot of stuff, but lets keep it simple.
In between the whole logic I am doing:

`insert into animals`...

Now I want all records which have been inserted into the `animals` table to be sent over email.
For example:

```
select * from animals where timestamp_loading > sysdate - 1/24        
-- now export this result and send over email
```

It could be via Excel file or just line by line written into an email.

Does anybody know any good function in PL/SQL Developer on how to do this?
I've seen that there is some sort of utl_mail Package which I could use.

Comment: Exactly, UTL_MAIL. What you saw is what you should use, so - why didn't you, already? Alternatively, use UTL_SMTP.

Comment: I am not really sure on how to use utl_mail to send the whole query result.

Comment: MESSAGE parameter accepts a VARCHAR2 datatype. Create a local variable of that datatype and compose the message in your PL/SQL procedure. Pass it to UTL_MAIL.SEND procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at Vsql-email app (you can search on google, I think I'm not allowed to post the direct link here), you can send the email as HTML formatted body and/or as an excel attachment, and no need to enable and configure Database Mail in SQL Server and write code for HTML formatting.